# NSURLSession Download restarts without calling any delegates

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I have been noticing a strange behavior on my app related to NSURLSession.

I use NSURLSession with a background configuration to start a download, the download starts without any problem, but at some point, apparently random, it stops for a few seconds, and restarts without calling any delegate other than

```
-URLSession: downloadTask: didWriteData: totalBytesWritten: totalBytesExpectedToWrite:
```

with a resetted number of bytes.

Can anyone tell me what's happening?

Here is how I initialize the session

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion] compare:@"8.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
{
    sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:sessionId];
}
else
{
    sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:sessionId];
}

sessionConfiguration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = kSimultaneousDownloads;
[sessionConfiguration setSessionSendsLaunchEvents:YES];
sessionConfiguration.discretionary = NO;

self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:self.backgroundQueue];
```

--EDIT--

I followed Rob's suggestions and using Charles and the xCode debbuger I found out that the order things happen are:

1. Create session
2. Call `getTasksWithCompletionHandler`, there are no tasks on the session
3. Starts a download task
4. Delegate `URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:` is called, I call completion handler `completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling,nil);`
5. Log from `didWriteData:` delegate shows download task with id 1 is downloading data, download shows on Charles with status Receiving response body
6. At some random point, I can see the download status changed to Complete on Charles, and a new one started
7. Delegate `URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:` is called, I call completion handler `completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling,nil);`
8. Log from `didWriteData:` delegate shows download task with id 2 is downloading data, the new download shows on Charles with status Receiving response body

Comment: Thanks for your answer, those are good ideas, I'll try those

Comment: There aren't any redirect or auth challenges, or at least it's not supposed to be redirecting ou authenticating

Comment: Sometimes redirects happen in situations you don't expect (e.g. presence or absence of `www` prefix). You really just need to watch this in Charles or some of these delegate methods to make sure.

Comment: I edited my question, I used Charles, I can't see any redirects, but the didReceiveChallenge: is in fact being called, just can't figure out why

Comment: Can the fact that I'm using a https URL be causing the delegate to be called? And if it can, why is part of the data being transmitted anyway?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of suggestions:

- Do you have any redirects or auth challenges involved here? Have you implemented those delegates to see if anything interesting is happening there?
- Have you tried watching this with [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) to see what is actually going on with the connection?

  This can be useful in diagnosing when the behavior is due to something actually happening in the connection versus some symptom resulting from our client-side code.
- Finally, is your `didWriteData` logging the task id (because with background sessions it can get confusing because a download initiated in a previous run of the app can finish up the next time you run the app).

Personally this last issue is the one that got me the most when I first started using background sessions. We're so accustomed to running app in the debugger, stopping, and re-running the app later with little residual effect of our prior session. But background sessions are vexing, because those old requests stay around unless you actually remove the app from the device/simulator.

Comment: I experienced the same residual effect.I just want to update files of the specific folder,any solution(except removing app from device)?!

Comment: In the end, your app has to handle this gracefully, so you just need to write delegates that expect and handle that scenario properly (keep track of what was already requested, don't request it again, handle it when it comes in a later session, etc.). My point is merely that this is an additional and fairly atypical wrinkle when debugging app (where previous debugging session can affect current one). I would have thought that `cancelAndInvalidate` would cancel any background requests you have going, tho I haven't needed to try that.